# Swarmplot from pandas with comma separated categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm working with a dataset that contains comma separated caategorical responses in its columns and am trying to plot a scatterplot similar to the one below. I think a correct approach might be to use a seaborn swarmplot, such as: `ax = sns.swarmplot(x="id", y="family", data=dftest)` but the result is far from what I'm looking for. I'm looking for some pointers on how can I work to reconstruct a similar plot?

[image: human perspectives scatterplot]

sample data:

| id | family | city | nation | world |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | next week, next few years | next week, next few years | lifetime | children's lifetime |
| 2 | next few years, lifetime | children's lifetime | next few years | next week, next few years, children's lifetime |
| 3 | next week, next few years | lifetime | children's lifetime | children's lifetime |
| 4 | next week, next few years | next few years | next week, next few years, lifetime, | next week, next few years, children's lifetime |
| 5 | next few years, lifetime | children's lifetime | children's lifetime | lifetime |

```
figure source: Meadows, D., Meadows, D., Randers, J. and Behrens, W., 1972. The Limits to growth. A report for the club of Rome's project on the predicament of mankind. 1st ed. New York: Universe Books.
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the expected output presented in the image is difficult to achieve with python's graph library, so I tried to mimic the desired output from seaborn's swarmplot. I hope this post will lead to some great answers from experienced engineers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
id family city nation world
1 "next week,next few years" "next week,next few years" lifetime "children's lifetime"
2 "next few years,lifetime" "children's lifetime" "next few years" "next week,next few years,children's lifetime"
3 "next week,next few years" lifetime "children's lifetime" "children's lifetime"
4 "next week,next few years" "next few years" "next week,next few years,lifetime," "next week,next few years,children's lifetime"
5 "next few years,lifetime" "children's lifetime" "children's lifetime" lifetime
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
dfs = pd.concat([
    df['family'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'family',1:'family'}),
    df['city'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'city',1:'city'}),
    df['nation'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'nation',1:'nation',2:'nation'}),
    df['world'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'world',1:'world',2:'world'})
], axis=1)

dfs = dfs.unstack().to_frame(name='TIME').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'SPACE'})
dfs['TIME'].replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True)
dfs.dropna(subset=['TIME'], inplace=True)

import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.swarmplot(x="TIME", y="SPACE", data=dfs, size=15)
ax.grid(which='minor', axis='both')
print(ax.get_ylim())
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 3.5)

for y_pos in [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]:
    ax.axhline(y=y_pos, color='k', lw=0.8)

for x_pos in [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]:
    ax.axvline(x=x_pos, color='k', lw=0.8)
```

[image]